# Performing arithmetic on an extracted part of a column

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file with the fields as follows

```
 1; 3435; 45--XY 
 2; 3436; 15--XY 
 3; 3437; 23--XY
```

I am required to multiply the first column with the numeric part of the last column, and then display them in an output file. How should I do this? I figure that **awk** would be the most straight-forward command.

Tried: `awk -F';' '{print substr($3,1,2)* $1}' input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: welcome to U&L, we are not a scripting/homework service, what have you tried ?

Comment: awk -F';' '{print substr($3,1,2)*  $1}' input.txt > output.txt

Comment: I think a combination of sed, to prepare the multiplication, and bc or dc, to calculate it, is a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

The simple

```
awk '{print $1 * $3}' input.txt
```

command will do the job. Extracting the numbers from the field doesn't needed in this case.

It is caused the number conversion mechanism of `awk` - [How awk Converts Between Strings and Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html#Strings-And-Numbers), namely:

> A string is converted to a number by interpreting any numeric prefix
>   of the string as numerals: "2.5" converts to 2.5, "1e3" converts to
>   1,000, and "25fix" has a numeric value of 25. Strings that can’t be
>   interpreted as valid numbers convert to zero.

**Output**

```
45
30
69
```

Answer (score 1):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -F';' '{ gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$NF); print $1*$NF }' input.txt > output.txt
```

- `gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",$NF)` - remove all non-digit characters `[^0-9]+` from the last field `$NF`

---

The `output.txt` content:

```
45
30
69
```